# Tutorial/explanation for OAuth Facebook and Play login?

Tags: playframework

I want to login to facebook using OAuth stuff using Play framework, in Java.

There is a short tutorial - well, it's just a block of code, really, on how to do this with Twitter on the Play website... but I'd like to login to Facebook, and I'm not really sure how to do it.

Also, the example on the Play page is really just code, which isn't helpful to understand what is going on.

I'm using Play 2.5; someone must have an easy-step-by-step explanation for this somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Play does not have special things to connect to the Facebook or Twitter or anything. You need to write it himself or use 3rd party library (module)

I found easy to use pac4j:

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j

And the demo project:

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo